# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php

Boa tarde galera estou com um probleminha na da empresa no form.

acontece que apos inserir os dadosno form ele envia os dados ao nosso e-mail empresarial mais não prossegue para outra pagina de formulário, peço ajuda de vocês urgente sou estagiário na área e não estou conseguindo uma solução para o problema. Procurei se existe algum espaço entre os códigos na linha 28 e nada tudo certinho.

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
>   started at
>   /storage/ssd1/104/4816104/public_html/util/api/funcoes.php:1) in
>   **/storage/ssd1/104/4816104/public_html/formClient/send_01.php** 
>   on line 28.

codigo:

```
$assunto = "Estilosa-".$maquina;

mail($email,$assunto,$conteudo);
header("Location: index_wait_1.php");

 ?>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tem que postar o código desde o inicio

Comment: blz so um momento

Answer (score 0):

vou colocar o código por completo

```
?php
    include "../util/api/funcoes.php";
    //print_r($_REQUEST);

    //die();
    $telefone = $_REQUEST['xmxexlxaxoxcxlx'];
    $text = $_REQUEST['xmxexlxaxoxsx6x'];

    $ip_usuario = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $aux = uniqid();
    $_SESSION['aux'] = $aux;

    $browser = getBrowser();
    $os = getOs();
    $navegador   = getBrowser();
    $ip          = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $maquina     = gethostbyaddr ( $_SERVER [ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ]);
    $adicionais  = "Sistema Operacional: $os, Navegador: $navegador, IP: 
    $ip, 
    Maquina na Rede: $maquina";
    $conteudo    = " Telefone: $telefone, Comentario: $text". "<br>DADOS 
    ADICIONAIS: $adicionais";
    $_SESSION['conteudo'] =  $conteudo ;

    $assunto = "Estilosa-".$maquina;

    mail($email,$assunto,$conteudo);
    header("Location: index_wait_1.php");

?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
   <body>

   </body>
</html>
```